# Firebase funnel event1's percentage higher than event2's percentage

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

[image]

I'm using the firebase analytics.
I want funnels well.
But funnel is strange...
There are event1, event2 and event3 ... on the image.
event2's percentage is about 340%. 
Why event2's percentage is higher than event1's percentage(100%)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase provides **open funnels**. Each step of the funnel is not required to be preceded by the previous funnel step. If you log step 2 of the funnel more times then step 1 you will see higher number of step 2. To implement **closed funnels** you can store a flag for each funnel step in SharedPreferences and only log subsequent steps when the flag is set. This will effectively make the funnel closed where each subsequent event is guaranteed to be preceded by previous event. You will have to decide on what exactly means to be preceded. For example if step 1 happens a year ago is step 2 considered part of the same funnel and so on.